# Which Sentence Is Written Correct?

Tags: sentence-choice

A. Checking the barometer, Elaine predicted good weather.

Or

B. Predicting good weather after Elaine checked the barometer.

I think A is correct and B is wrong because the gerund "predicting" needs to be a "ed" suffix.

Answer (score 1):

> A. Checking the barometer, Elaine predicted good weather.

Sentence A is correct.

> B. Predicting good weather after Elaine checked the barometer.

This is grammatically wrong. Here, the given structure is "N + after + S + V + O". There's a lonely noun before the "after" without any friend, which is pretty sad :'( . You should have a full clause before "after" in this case.

You can correct sentence B by changing it a bit:

> Elaine predicted good weather after she checked the barometer.
>   Prediction of good weather came after Elaine checked the barometer.
>   As Elaine checked the barometer, she predicted good weather.